# The actual source of pst-plot?

Tags: best-practices, pst-plot, source

In the comment to answer to his question [Labels with \psplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149079/labels-with-psplot/149084#149084) Svend Tveskæg writes:
The newest version of pst-plot can be found at http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot.tex.

Is it the best place for searching the newest version of this package? The results, produced by different versions, were completely different, at least in the mentioned case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as a general rule, i would always recommend using the ctan copy, which is in this case at [in the ctan graphics tree](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/tex/pst-plot.tex)

as it happens (in this case) the “private” copy of the file is the same as that on ctan.

in general, one shouldn't count on that, since the "private" location may be an experimental version offered for testing.

finally -- remember that (almost) all tex/latex/context packages are provided by the author's grace and favour, and you should always report bugs as best you can, to help the development process.